# Sugestões para aplicativo gerenciador de impressoras

Tags: impressora

Eu estou mais ambientado com webdev, e gostaria de sugestões de como poderia implementar uma idéia. Notem, que não estou pedindo nenhum script, nem forma de fazer, mas gostaria de dicas de quais ferramentas/linguagem mais apropriada para fazer algo próximo ao que eu gostaria.

A minha idéia seria criar um mini-app, executável em windows, com interface gráfica.

A idéia do app é instalar as impressoras de rede, diretórios, executar algumas funções como limpeza de cache do navegador, etc.

Eu consigo fazer tudo isso com scripts batch, oferecendo menus para o usuário escolher o que necessita, também sei que poderia automatizar tudo isto, mas ainda assim não é meu propósito.

É possível fazer algo parecido com ambiente gráfico, oferecendo um menu para o usuário?

Estou olhando o visual studio, mas não tenho certeza que este é o melhor caminho.

Eu sei que isto não é aplicável para outros ambientes além do próprio que pretendo utilizar, mas mesmo assim, gostaria de tentar, por puro aprendizado de outra linguagem qualquer para desktop.

Sugestões?

Answer (score 1):

O Próprio windows, versão server tem um servidor de impressão, onde vc pode definir prioridades, restrições, ex: Usuário X imprimi com prioridade, usuário Y só na impressora PB, etc.

Já utilizei isso na época com o windows 2003.
E toda configurações fazia pela intranet nossa que era em ASP Classic...é faz tempo..rs
Mas se era possível naquela época hoje ainda é.
Para isso era manipular o metadata do windows, existia até alguns exemplos no próprio windows.